# Unique I'd based on ip +port

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a script to update a list of servers based on incoming ip and supplied port in php.

This would be for the database to hold short term (life of heartbeat from server) ie:

Server 127.0.0.1:9999 sends a update to this script which will then has that as a unique string which would return the same unique hash always.

This way the rest of the script can choose to update or add a new entry to the table as the hash would be its key.

Does anyone have any suggestions on the type of hash to use for this to prevent collisions. I would t imagine there being more then 10 thousand entrees even on a good day but I'd rather plan for the extreme of 100,000 unique ip+port to hash as a string to a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can add another table to your db with your key as a key and a counter-id. With inserting or finding your key in this table you get a uniqe integer id.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I usually use for password salts. It should work in your case too.

```
$salt_random = mcrypt_create_iv(128, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
$salt = hash('sha512', $salt_random);
```

But if you want to be extra safe, you could generate it recursively checking against the existing ones.

I hope, I could be of any help.